# How to skip Server Snaps step on custom ISO installer

Tags: 20.04, preseed, custom-installer

I'm building a custom 20.04 Server ISO and I would like to skip server snaps selection step during interactive installation.  My understanding is it would be possible to do using preseed or autoinstall but I couldn't find in the docs how to do it.

Comment: I would suggest to also ask it in this topic: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/automated-server-installs/16612 the creator of autoinstall is in there ;-) (and since he had to redo preseed he also knows tons of stuff about that)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve that using autoinstall, using interactive-sections as follow:

```
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  interactive-sections:
    - locale
    - identity
    - keyboard
    - network
    - proxy
    - storage
    - apt
    - ssh
```

I was looking for a way to tell it that snaps would be the only non-interactive sections, but according to documentation it's not possible.

Comment: offical docs: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#interactive-sections